# Margins in Safari

Tags: css, safari, margin

My Website has three elements, a text, a text box and a button.
In Chrome everything looks like expected but when i use safari it looks completely different.

```css
.text-input {
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.button {
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}
```

### Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

### Safari:

[image: Safari]

Comment: Please edit your question to include your HTML. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: please add your html also